# chart.js - How to show multiple tooltip

Tags: charts, chart.js

I Using Chart.js V4.2.1
And I'm trying to show multiple tooltip in ChartJS like below.

[i want to show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90a9X.png)

I want to show both February and May when I point to February.
is there any way show up multi tooltips promatically?

I try to add some tooltip plugins but i don't know how to do it..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Datalabel plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/line.html) might be useful for you. If you don't want to show labels for all datapoints, by modifying display function you can control which ones are shown.

Multiple tooltips is something I currently need as well, and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to do this feature directly.